# Encrypt keystore password in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, server.xml

Tried to encrypt the keystorepass by following the steps mentioned in this link - [Encrypt tomcat keystore password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194052/encrypt-tomcat-keystore-password/54308813#54308813)

My server.xml looks like this

```html
<Connector port="8443" protocol="<my custom class>"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
          keystoreFile="conf/.ssl/keystore.jks"        
           keystorePass="<encrypted_password>"/>
```

I also setup my password decoder as mentioned here

```html
public class Http11Nio2Protocol extends org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol {

@Override
public void setKeystorePass(String s) {
    try {
        super.setKeystorePass(new EncryptService().decrypt(s));
    } catch (final Exception e){
        super.setKeystorePass("");
    }
}
```

The problem is the tomcat doesnt start with these changes and i get the following error

> 

```
**org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[MyCustomClass-8443]]**
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:643)
    at com.adventnet.mfw.service.WebService.start(WebService.java:86)
    at com.adventnet.mfw.service.ServiceStarter.initServices(ServiceStarter.java:170)
    at com.zoho.mickey.startup.MEServer.startServer(MEServer.java:328)
    at com.adventnet.mfw.Starter.start(Starter.java:367)
    at com.adventnet.mfw.Starter.main(Starter.java:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint.bind(Nio2Endpoint.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:941)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133)
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
    ... 25 more
```

Help me on how to proceed with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the rest of the stack trace. It looks like your custom class failed, but we don't know anything about your custom class or why it may have failed.

Comment: I have also added my custom class' implementation in my original post itself. Http11Nio2Protocol is my custom class. Also, Added the entire error trace. updated in the post.. please check.

Comment: Where is your password being stored? How is it being used?

Comment: I encrypt my password using my own algorithm.  I hav no specific usage pattern.  Just the way tomcat handles the plain text password. I just try to decrypt the password using the same algorithm in my custom class.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchultz . It worked now.  There was a problem in my decrypting class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `custom class` as a jar inside the **tomcat\lib** folder. Also check the keystore is in the right location - "`conf/.ssl/keystore.jks`"

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh.  It worked now.  There was a problem in my decrypting class.