# Encrypting just the password in server.xml while using the default Http11Nio2Protocol as protocol for keystores in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, encryption, keystore

[Encrypt tomcat keystore password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194052/encrypt-tomcat-keystore-password)

With reference to the above question.

What if I want to just encrypt the password with some jar file in the tomcat/lib folder, using the just the org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol as protocol. Do I need to add some attribute to call the encryption class from the jar file.

Comment: You need to extend the `Http11Nio2Protocol` class like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36563846/11748454) and use your class in the configuration.

Comment: I am using some encrypting jar, I am not allowed to change the jar. Just I need to check whether this jar which is used for encryption of datasource and can even be used for encryption of passwords in keystore.

Comment: The [aforementioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36563846/11748454) doesn't require you to change anything in your jar. You just have to extend Tomcat to support (reversible) password encryption using the functions in your encryption jar, put the extended `HttpNio2Protocol` class in another jar and deploy it in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` along with your encryption jar.